# Lombok EqualsAndHashCode handling optional arrays

Tags: java, lombok

I have a series of POJOs that I've been using Lombok to fill out and things have been pretty smooth. I've started making things optional using Java 8's Optional<> class, but I've run into a snag when making a byte array optional. In my unit tests, comparing objects worked fine comparing two instances of this class built the same way:

```
@NoArgsConstructor @Getter @Setter @EqualsAndHashCode @ToString
public class Attachment {
  private String contentType;
  private LanguageCode language;
  private byte[] data;
  private URI url;
  private String title;
}
```

I can make contentType, language, url, and title all Optional<> and the tests still pass, but the test suddenly fail when I make data optional.

```
private Optional<byte[]> data;
```

Result:

```
expected
[Attachment(contentType=Optional[UTF-8], language=Optional[en], data=Optional[[B@27eb3298], url=Optional[test://testuri], title=Optional[test text])]
but found
[Attachment(contentType=Optional[UTF-8], language=Optional[en], data=Optional[[B@200a26bc], url=Optional[test://testuri], title=Optional[test text])]
```

Is there any specific way to handle optional arrays so that lombok can handle the comparisons?

Comment: Is it you who registred this as a bug? https://code.google.com/p/projectlombok/issues/detail?id=798&q=array&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Target%20Component%20Owner%20Summary

If not, there are at least one other person experiencing the same problem. My guess is that it is a bug. Lombok  previously had some Java 8 related problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lombok has special magic; it knows that arrays don't adhere to the equals contract properly and uses Arrays.equals instead.

Optional<> is not as smart as lombok and didn't consider this. We can't really fix that; it's a problem with optional.

Optional in general is a very bad idea anywhere outside of the very limited domain of returning it from stream API methods. You shouldn't use it here, especially not as the type of any field or any parameter. Just don't use it. This goes doubly so for arrays; just use an empty array.

NB: Generics and arrays don't mix. Reason #9103 that optional is a bad idea for java.

Comment: This is, unfortunately, the conclusion we came to. We attempted to incorporate Optional into our API, but ran into many problems that simply had no solution. With Optional, the only winning move is not to play.